# Snap.svg equivalent to RaphaelJS's setStart and setFinish?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

In RaphaelJS, you can create a "set" of elements. When you transform this set, it transforms all elements in the set using a common origin (as opposed to each element having its own origin). An easy example of this:

```
paper.setStart();
path = paper.path(string);
path = paper.path(string);
path = paper.path(string);
set = paper.setFinish();
set.transform("T0,0R0S3,3,0,0");
```

I'm working on replacing RaphaelJS with Snap.SVG for a project. There is no equivalent to `setStart()` and `setFinish()`. Snap.svg does have Sets though according to the documentation. But it is not clear how to create a set and/or add elements to that set.

What is the equivalent? How do I work with sets in Snap.svg?

Answer (score 0):

Try Snap.set, eg

```
var mySet = Snap.set();
mySet.push( mySvgElement );
```

If you do a selectAll on a container element, it will return a set as well,
like s.selectAll('path');